# Hexadecimal -> Float Conversion Inaccurate

Tags: java, string, floating-point, bigdecimal, data-conversion

I'm using the following code to convert a hexadecimal `String` to a floating point `String`:

```
private static String removeScientificNotation(float value)
{
    return new BigDecimal(Float.toString(value)).toPlainString();
}

/**
 * Converts a hexadecimal value to its single precision floating point representation
 *
 * @param hexadecimal The <code>hexadecimal</code> to convert
 * @return The converted value
 */
public static String hexadecimalToFloatingPoint(String hexadecimal)
{
    Long longBits = Long.parseLong(hexadecimal, 16);
    Float floatValue = Float.intBitsToFloat(longBits.intValue());

    return removeScientificNotation(floatValue);
}
```

To test this, I wrote the following `JUnit` test:

```
public class TestConversions
{
    @Test
    public void testConversions()
    {
        String floatValue = Conversions.hexadecimalToFloatingPoint("40000000");
        Assert.assertEquals(floatValue, "2.0");
        floatValue = Conversions.hexadecimalToFloatingPoint("50000000");
        Assert.assertEquals(floatValue, "8589934592");
        floatValue = Conversions.hexadecimalToFloatingPoint("C0000000");
        Assert.assertEquals(floatValue, "-2.0");
    }
}
```

However, the 2nd assertion fails. According to various online converters like [this one](https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/), `50000000` should be converted to `8589934592` but Java returns `8589934600`.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :8589934600
Actual   :8589934592
```

Which result is correct now? If Java is wrong then how do I correct it?

Comment: I suspect what you're seeing is that only 7 significant digits of precision should be relied on for `float`... (Try returning `float` instead of `String`, and comparing your result to 8589934600f)

Comment: Note that the closest *exact float value* to 8589934600 is 8589934592.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't do exact comparisons with floats. For assertions in unit tests, there is `Assert#equals(floatA, floatB, delta)`.

Comment: bully  please find my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by direct passing float value to BigDecimal constructor like below.Cause of problem is `Float.toString(value)`( As this method is make internal call to `FloatingDecimal` and `toJavaFormatString` its seems to do some rounding on values) so no need to use Float.toString instead just pass your actual float value.

```
    String myString = "50000000";
    Long i = Long.parseLong(myString, 16);
    Float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(i.intValue());
    String finalString= new BigDecimal(f).toPlainString();
    System.out.println("final value  "+finalString);
```

So  just change your method like below.

```
private static String removeScientificNotation(float value)
{
    return new BigDecimal(value).toPlainString();
}
```

Comment: The specific problem with `Float.toString(value)` is that it picks, from the range of decimals that would convert to `value`, the one with the fewest significant digits, not the exact value. Good for display, not good for this purpose.

Comment: Just a side note, there is no need to use `Long` and `Float` instead of the actual `long` and `float` types. Calling `intValue()` on a `Long` is only obfuscating the type cast from `long` to `int` that happens here. Besides that, it only incorporates unnecessary boxing and unboxing.